# How to filter Microsoft Graph API JSON response using Power Query language?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, powerapps-canvas

My request is

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$select=appRoles
```

[image]

Because of this I have a problem in PowerApps, I can't show the objects.

Comment: It's not possible to return nested properties without specifying the parent property

Comment: @Imad, in the future, if you anonymize the JSON response (removed any sensitive data) and include it in your post, we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you have...**

- ... a working Custom Connector named `myCustConn`
- ... with a GET method called `GetRoles`

**try this:**

In the PowerApp, insert a Button control and set its `OnSelect` property to:

- `ClearCollect(colAppRoles, myCustConn.GetRoles().value.AppRoles)`

Then insert a Gallery control and set its `Items` property to:

- `colAppRoles`

Then insert a TextBox control *into the Gallery template* and set its `Default` property to:

- `ThisItem.description` (or `ThisItem.id`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you sow much. I have another question if tou can answer it to me. How can I put in a variable for example ThisItems.id to compare it later to make a button visible or not in powerapps.

Comment: It might be better to create a separate StackOverflow question. Tag me and I can answer it there.